# Is there a way to change a slot name before rendering the element in the shadowDOM, based on which slot is used in the DOM?

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, lit

I'm working on a project that has different features for desktop and mobile devices. Some of these features can be replaced by slots. I'm trying to have one slot be able to be replaced by *either* a desktop slot named `poster-foreground`, or a mobile slot named `mobile-poster-foreground`, but default to `poster-foreground` if no mobile slot is applied (this is necessary due to current client implementations).

Currently I have it rendering the slot and changing its name upon render, based on whether its desktop or mobile, and based on the arbitrary  variable `mobilePosterSlotted`, where `mobilePosterSlotted` is set to true if an attribute `enable-mobile-poster-slot` is set on the element (to not mess with current client implementations), like this:

```
private [$renderPosterIcon]() {
    let slotName = (this.mobilePosterSlotted && this[$isMobile]) ? "mobile-poster-foreground":"poster-foreground";
    let imageName = (this.mobilePosterSlotted && this[$isMobile]) ? "mobile-poster-foreground-image":"poster-foreground-image";

      return html`
        <slot name=${slotName} slot=${slotName} @slotchange=${this[$handleSlotChange]}>
           <figure class=${slotName} part=${slotName} slot=${slotName} >
             <img 
               class=${imageName}
               part=${imageName}
               src=${this.posterForeground} 
               alt="Clickable poster image to uncover 3D model viewer"/>
           </figure>
        </slot>
      `;
  }
```

where the `renderPosterIcon` function is called upon page load. I'd like it to be able to detect if the slot being used is either `poster-foreground` or `mobile-poster-foreground` *before* rendering the poster icon, and then render the slot name based on which of those slots is being used (without relying on an arbitrary variable/attribute being set), but I'm not sure if this is possible to do before rendering the element itself. Is there a different way I could go about this?

Comment: Are you familiar with <template> elements? They allow you to do exactly what (i think) you're asking (analyze markup and DOM node structure before any of it is actually rendered - and if needed, reorganize it or display things conditionally). Templates can have slots inside them or themselves can be named slots. Anything inside of a template will not be rendered until explicitly told to do so but you can still analyze the structure of the markup inside it by accessing its 'content' property. Were I not on mobile i'd try posting some examples

Answer (score 0):

I figured out at least one solution.

This checks all children for a slot value of "mobile-poster-foreground", and if it exists, sets a boolean check to true. I put this before returning the html and it seems to work like a charm.

```
    let childElements = this.children;
    let mobilePosterSlotted;
    for(let child of childElements) {
      if(child.slot==="mobile-poster-foreground") mobilePosterSlotted = true;
    }

    let slotName = (mobilePosterSlotted && this[$isMobile]) ? "mobile-poster-foreground":"poster-foreground";
    let imageName = (mobilePosterSlotted && this[$isMobile]) ? "mobile-poster-foreground-image":"poster-foreground-image";  

    /* return html here*/
```